# Access form in directive from controller angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

Hello I have a form which i created on a directive. what I would like to do is be able to see this form and fields in a controller to be able to add for example some type of validation to each field such as form.field1.$error.validationError. Thank you for your help!

html index:

```
..some code
<my-Form dataObj="dataObj"></my-Form>
```

html my-form-dir:

```
 <form name="myForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
         <label>Name</label>
             <input ng-model="dataObj.name" value="{{dataObj.name}}" ng-required='true' ng-minlength="3"/>
       </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container flex>
             <label>Date</label>
             <md-datepicker ng-model="dataObj.endDate" name="dataObj" ng-required='true' md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
           </md-input-container>
</form>
```

js:

```
var newData = angular.module('newData',[]);

newData.controller('DataController', function() {
    //would like to access form here
})

newData.directive('myForm', function() {
   return {
    scope: {
        dataObj: '='
    }
    templateUrl: 'myForm.html'
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    }
   };

})
```

Comment: Where is the content of `myForm.html`?

Comment: its in the same folder as index.html, the form displays great! what I am trying to do is access the form through the js file

Comment: No, what I mean is: in your question which is the HTML code contained in the `myForm.html` file? You did not identify it clearly.

Comment: @Sébastien I have updated my question with the response

Comment: with your update, it's not really clear what the problem is, `dataObj` should be accessible on `$scope` in the controller....  I wrote a simplistic example that is essentially the same as this except the variables and form is a bit different:  http://plnkr.co/edit/Ww7P2iauLHHCmCKV4D6i?p=preview

Comment: @Claies thank you for your response! This is a great idea however, my main goal is to add error messages to the form by validating. The problem is i am unable to do so until I am able to grab the form itself so I can do something similar to: form.field1.$error.validationError

Comment: that's a different situation entirely.  essentially, you won't be able to do form validation form the outer controller, because the form is inside the directive's scope.  you can try passing the form out of the directive back to the controller, but your form names would have to be unique for each instance of the form, so there is some logic required there to get a unique name.  It's not an easy task.

Comment: @Claies Thank you for letting me know. I was able to do a different solution, I added a validation in the directive as well as my controller, not the ideal solution but it works for now. thank you again